# Creating SSH keys to login into remote machines as root user

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, root

I have followed the process of creating the public and private keys so that I can login in to remote system without a password.

But I would like to login into the remote system as root user without password using SSH keys.

For example, `vm2$ssh vm1@10.0.0.1` would give me `vm1$` prompt but I need `ssh vm1@10.0.0.1` to give me `vm1#`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, though this is not a recommended setup.

To login as root user, you need to specify that you *want* the root user. The command would be

```
ssh root@10.0.0.1
```

Of course, this only logs in, so in order to use your keys, you have to copy them:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@10.0.0.1
```

You'll be prompted for password once. After that, you can SSH as the root user on `10.0.0.1` with the first command.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa root@10.0.0.1` when I am giving this command and entering the password its showing `Permission Denied, please try again`

Comment: @karra You'll need to enter the root password, or try something else (I'll add it later).

Comment: Sorry if its naive. The password for `$sudo -s` and the root password are same. right ?

Comment: @karra yeah it is, but you need the root password of the remote machine

Comment: yes, I am entering the remote machine password. I have even checked on the remote machine

Comment: @karra Then it's possible that the remote machine has disabled root login. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote machine and look for `PermitRootLogin`. Change it to `yes` to add your key, and change it to `prohibit-password` after you're done.

Comment: `Info: 1 key(s) remain to be installed` and I am getting permission denied. Initially, I have changed it to yes and then tried. `StrictModes` is this related to this configuration ?